# Should a database table exist in more than one edmx file?

Tags: entity-framework-4, edmx

Let's say I have an existing database with about 90 tables. I've seen comments that state including them all into one big edmx file is not considered good practice. Suppose I have logical groupings like HR, Legal, and Accounting that I can use to create multiple edmx files. That makes sense. However, what I don't know is what to do if each of these logical groupings would contain a foreign key to commonly used tables (like employee, address, etc). Should each edmx file contain these tables as well, or is there a better way to handle this?

On a side note, when creating an edmx file, how small is too small? Is a context with 5 entities too small? 2? Is there a general rule of thumb?

Any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the runtime perspective it should not really matter whether you split your model to multiple edmx files or not. 90 entities should be fine but you may start seeing some delay when your app starts. If you experience this you may want pregenerate views which should address the issue. The EF designer is known to be slow if you have many entities. The EF Designer in VS 2012 however allows to have multiple diagrams per model to visualize subsections of your overall model. 
If you think you will be able to manage the model easily without splitting it then you can try going with just one model. If it becomes unmanagable then you can think about splitting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this doesn't answer question. If I do decide to go with more than one model, how do I handle the tables that would be needed by all of them (eg Employees, Address, etc)? For each model, would these tables be included?

Comment: I believe that you would need to use fully qualified names of entities (and because all non-primitive types are always fully qualified it should just work). Try creating just two related entities and put them in separate files to check if this is going to work.